# Is persistent homology mathematically “interesting”?

Tags: soft-question, data-analysis, research

Currently, I am occupying myself with (non-applied perspectives on) *Persistent Homology*, having a background in non-applied maths (representation theory).

After having spent some time on the topic however, it seems to me that this field is already very grazed, leading to the following:

**Question:** Which new mathematical insights can be attributed to this field, if any? Should one expect that there will be any? Or should I predominantly expect applications on actual data-driven problems?

**Concerns:**

- By a persistent module $M$, it seems that one understands a graded $k[x]$-module (or, more general, a graded module over the ring $\bigoplus_{\mathbf R_{\geq 0}} k$ with grading in a monoid). The *fundamental theorem of persistent homology* states that $M$ decomposes as a direct sum of *interval modules* $k_{[i, j)}$, which is the module whose degree-$l$-part is $k$ if $l\in[i, j)$ and zero otherwise.

  This is just the classification of f.g. modules over a PID; haven't they been aware of this?
- A neat generalisation is to consider general posets for the grading, and not only $\mathbf Z$ or $\mathbf R$. To this end, one considers the $k[x]$-module $M$ as a representation of the category $\mathbf Z$ with morphisms $i\leq j$; [Bubenik/Scott](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00454-014-9573-x) and [Bauer/Lesnick](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.10085) takes some effort to develop a categorical view on persistent homology.

  Are there any researchers pursuing this further? Until now, I have only found articals that employ this neat formalism of abstraction, without going beyond the basics in persistent homology.

Comment: I cannot parse what your first question is asking:  "So, is it realistic that there are any proper insights *about do come* in the field around persistent homolgy/TDA?"  Specifically, did you intend to write the words I italicized?  Or is it a typo, so perhaps that phrase should be *about to come*?

Comment: @amWhy  The phrase would have been "about to come". Rephrased the question.

Comment: Have you checked out Steve Oudot's work? (https://geometrica.saclay.inria.fr/team/Steve.Oudot/)